# Issue with removing previous markers and centerMark after creating polygons in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm developing an application that creates polygons with markers at vertices using the Google Maps API. However, the markers and centerMark from the previously created polygons remain on the map every time a new polygon is created.

The goal is to remove all previous markers and add markers for new vertices every time a new polygon is drawn. Here is a portion of the code

```
// When a new shape is drawn
drawingManager.addListener('overlaycomplete', (event) => {
  if (currentOverlay) {
    currentOverlay.setMap(null);
    setCurrentOverlay(null);
  }

  if (centerMarker) {
    centerMarker.setMap(null);
    setCenterMarker(null);
  }
  vertexMarkers.forEach((marker) => {
    if (marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }
  });

  // rest of the code...

  if (event.type === window.google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
    // rest of the code...
    
    vertices.addListener('insert_at', () => {
      newVertexMarkers.forEach((marker) => {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      newVertexMarkers = [];
      
      // rest of the code...
    });

    polygon.addListener('click', (event) => {
      // rest of the code...
    });

    vertices.addListener('insert_at', () => {
      newVertexMarkers.forEach((marker) => {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      newVertexMarkers = [];

      // rest of the code...
    });

    setCenterMarker(centerMarker);
  }
});

return () => {
  if (drawingManager) {
    window.google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(drawingManager);
    drawingManager.setMap(null);
  }

  if (currentRadiusLine) {
    currentRadiusLine.setMap(null);
  }

  if (currentRadiusLabel) {
    currentRadiusLabel.setMap(null);
  }

  if (centerMarker) {
    centerMarker.setMap(null);
  }

  vertexMarkers.forEach((marker) => {
    if (marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }
  });
};
```

The above code attempts to remove the previously created polygons and its markers every time a new polygon is drawn. However, the markers and centerMark drawn previously still remain on the map. The **setMap(null)** method, as I understand, is used to remove markers from the map, yet the previous markers aren't removed in this instance.

**vertexMarkers** and **centerMarker** are state variables used to track the markers.

How can I resolve this issue? I'm not sure why the previously drawn markers and centerMark remain on the map. If you have any suggestions that could help in solving this problem, please let me know.

Here's the updated version with the console output:

```
newVertexMarkers.forEach((marker) => {
  marker.setMap(null);
  console.log('Marker after first null', marker);
});
```

After running this code, I get the following output on the console: Marker after first null Marker {**gm: {...}, gm_accessors*: {...}, position: LatLng, gm_bindings*: {...}, map: null, ...}.

In this console output, the **map** property of the marker is **null**, which suggests that the marker has been successfully removed from the map. However, even after setting **map** to **null**, the marker still appears on the map when a new polygon is drawn. This is the main issue I am facing. I'm not sure why the marker remains visible on the map, and I'm looking for assistance to understand and resolve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This platform have a functionality wherein you can insert html/css/javascript code to run it and see the output in your question itself. Can you do that? That would be beneficial in increasing your chances of getting help here.

Comment: For more information, please read how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)